# Remove Items from System Configuration utilities startup tab

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Everyone know msconfig utility that come with windows to control a lot of things, how I can delete entry from the list that come on start up tab?

EDIT:
I don't want to do it by any program, can I do it by removing something from the registry?

Comment: There are quite a few places in the registry that can startup programs. That's what most viruses rely on. I suggest that you follow the advice below and use autoruns, which looks in all of these places. Autoruns sorts the entries by their place in the registry, which will also give you the answer(s) to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) has the feature to do that , Tools->Startup

Comment: do you have any other way?